# JSON.Stringify error "Cannot Read Property [uuid] of Undefined" on THREE.js Object3D

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, stringify

I just refactored one of the top-level object types in my THREE.js app to be an Object3D() so that I can make full use of the parent/child relationships available.

The problem I'm running into is that now, when I attempt to save files, I'm getting this error at `JSON.stringify()`:

```
three.min.js:486 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'AA3E2259-803A-4F50-8567-9D8DA246ABC7' of undefined
    at b (three.min.js:486)
    at B.toJSON (three.min.js:487)
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at saveFile (fileHandlingUtils.js:150)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (app.js:34)
```

The offending uuid is not that of the Object3D but of it's material. My thought is that for some reason `JSON.Stringify()` thinks the uuid is the key and not the value in the key/value pair. Not sure why this would be.

Also strange that it's saying something is 'undefined.' I'm not sure what's coming in undefined, and I'm not sure where to look. Prior to calling `JSON.Stringify()` the data being called in as the first parameter of `JSON.Stringify()` appears to be there fine.

Here's the relevant code:

```
var circularRefs = [        /* Toplevel File Admin Paramas */
                            'fullpath',
                            'data',
                            'cognition',
                            /* GraphElement Params */
                            'nodes',
                            'edges',
                            /* Edge Params */
                            'sourceNode',
                            'targetNode',
                            /* Shared GraphElement Params */
                            'ID',
                            'name',
                            'color',
                            'text',
                            'r', 
                            'g', 
                            'b', 
                            'position',
                            'x',
                            'y',
                            'z', 
                            'opacity', 
                            'label', 
                            'labelColor', 
                            'labelOpacity',
                            'labelFontSize',
                            'castShadow',
                            'receiveShadows', 
                            /* Group Params */ 
                            'groups', 
                        /*  'edges',    --- Causes circular ref error */
                            /* Node Params */ 
                            'radius', 
                            'shape' 
                    ];

var saveFile = function( filename, content, url ){

    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var body = {};
    var jBody;

    if ( url ){
        body.fullpath = url + '/' + filename;       // filename includes ext        
    }           
    else if ( !url || url === "" ){
        body.fullpath = filename; 
    }

    body.data = content;

    jBody = JSON.stringify( body, circularRefs );

    // Send the request
    httpRequest.open("POST", '/save', true);
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8" );
    httpRequest.send( jBody );  

    console.log( httpRequest );
};
```

The `savefile` function is called when the user clicks the "Save As" button, which is an HTML-based button. `cognition` is an object that contains arrays of 'Nodes" and "Edges." The problem reported here started when I changed Nodes from being their own object type:

`Node = function( params ){ .... }...
 var n = new Node...`

to being THREE.Object3D()s...

```
function addNode( params ){
      var node = new THREE.Object3D();
      node.name = ... 

      ... scene.add( node );
}
```

Here's the code on calling the `saveFile()` function:

```
document.getElementById('saveAsBtn').addEventListener( 'click', function(){ 
                                                                        saveFile( ( fileNameFromInput() + ".json" ) , cognition, "./userfiles" );
                                                                                    toggleSaveAsBoxOff(); } );
```

Thanks for the help.

---

UPDATE: Following suggestion from pailhead below I swapped three.js (non-minified) in for three.min.js. I'm running r91 of the non-minified version, and was running r85 of the minified version.

Now with r91 of both minified and non-minified versions, I am no longer getting the error. But...

With the old version of the app, where the Node is its own object-type, things are saving as they were previously (that's good and consistent). With the new version, where the Node is an Object3D(), when I go to save the file, the file is saved with the nodes as empty objects.

Save from old file version (own object type):

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "ID": "n000",
      "name": "n000",
      "color": {
        "r": 128,
        "g": 128,
        "b": 255
      },
      "position": {
        "x": 4.280913954264392,
        "y": 13.520686329165372,
        "z": 10.4285750679757
      },
      "opacity": 0.75, ...
```

... that's good.

Save from new version (Object3D):

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}, ...
```

That's bad. What's interesting is that the correct number of nodes is being captured, so I suspect that it may have something to do with the way things are being excluded. But I have no idea where to start and Googling hasn't turned up much.

Thanks again...

Comment: you haven't shown how you call `saveFile`

Comment: @JaromandaX I just added how I call saveFile and some additional clarification. Hope it helps.

Comment: Try running this with an unminified version of three.js (`three.js` instead of `three.min.js`) this will give you somewhat more meaningful errors. (For example, i've no idea what the variable `b` does, nor `B`), after that, this kind of stuff is best debugged with debugging tools like the one the Chrome browser has. Without much code, or something live, people can pretty much only guess at whats going on here. With a debugger you could put breakpoints at various lines and figure out how you ended up in this state.

Comment: @pailhead thanks for the suggestion. I replaced the minified version as suggested in both the the forked version of my app (where I'm making nodes Object3D's as above, and the original). Interesting result. In the original app, everything is working as it did previously. In the forked version I'm not getting the error and the file is saving, but I am getting empty objects for each of the nodes. I'll make an edit to my post to reflect that in a moment...

Comment: same version of threejs?

Comment: that doesnt make a whole lot of sense :)

Comment: Running r91 on the non-minified version. Not sure how to check the version on the minified.

Comment: I think it still reports the version in the console. Or you can look for `REVISION`

Comment: Revision 85 on the minified.

Comment: Now updated to r91 of minified, both minified & non-minified are behaving consistently as would be expected. But... as noted in my update, now saved files simply have empty objects on the new version of the app.